# How to wget and write filename based on server last modified date?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, wget

I'd like to download a website via wget in Bash, but only pages modified after a set date. For example, if I wanted to download Stack Overflow, but only on pages modified after 12/1/2014. I'd further like to write the timestamp of the modified date from the server into the local filename.

Using wget, here's what I've come up with so far:

```
wget -m -r -l 9 -t 3 -T 15 -O snapshot-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`.htm -R js,css,jpg,png,gif,pdf,mpg,mp3,mpeg,au,wav,docx,JS,CSS,JPG,PNG,GIF,PDF,MPG,MP3,MPEG,AU,WAV,DOCX,asx,asf,ASX,ASF,WMV,wmv,wma,WMA -erobots=off http://www.example.com
```

This, however, gets me the date the file was downloaded, not the server modified date.

Can anyone help me fix this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking `wget` with the `-O` option causes all the files downloaded to be concatenated into a single output file, with no indication as to where each individual file starts. Since there will be more than one downloaded file in the `snapshot` archive, and presumably they have different modified dates, it doesn't seem possible to satisfy the request.

Also, note that `-m` implies `-N`, which is not compatible with `-O` (as explained in the [`wget` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html#Download-Options)).

If you want to preserve the modified dates of all the files, I suggest that you download them individually using the `-N` option (and without the `-O` option, letting `wget` apply the name of the file itself). You could then rename the files in a postprocessing step, using each file's modification date in the new filename. (Hint: `stat -c %y` or `stat -c %z`). But you need to be aware that not all sites provide accurate dates.

If you want to preserve more information from the HTTP response, you could specify the `--save-headers` option, which will prepend the headers to each saved file. You can then postprocess the files to extract and remove the headers (the file itself starts immediately after the first blank line).

Finally, the use of `-erobots=off` is generally considered unfriendly (or even a violation of acceptable use policies) since it can lead to excessive server load. You should not specify this option on a recursive request for a site not under your control unless you have permission from the site administrator.